# SelectionTree Hide options

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8

I read lots about how to show or remove installation options for features in 
the `SelectionTree`.

1. Will be installed on local hard drive.
2. Entire feature will be unavailable.

I don't have any subfeatures, still option 2 i.e. Entire feature will be unavailable. is getting displayed.
For e.g.

```
<Feature Id="ABC" Title="ABC ShortCut" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />   
</Feature>
```

Is there any way to hide option 2, show only "Will be installed on local hard drive".
I have checked [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503174/set-sub-features-to-not-install-by-default), but not get any proper answer there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't if you deploy as .MSI

The only option is to deploy with an .EXE (that calls MsiSetExternalUI and takes care of the UI) like Burn.