# How to set the level of feature based on condition in wix?

Tags: wix

I am trying to install the features based on the condition. Initially i set the feature level to 1 and place a condition inside the feature to modify the feature level.

I am unable to modify the feature level and it is always set to 1 only irrespective of condition.

```
<Feature
        Id = "AddinsFeature"
        Title  = "InstallAddin"
        Level  = "1"
        Absent="allow">
      <ComponentRef Id = "AddInComp"/>
        <Condition Level="0">
          <![CDATA[FALSE]]>
        </Condition>
</Feature>
```

Comment: You should take a closer look at the installation log file. The `INSTALLLEVEL` property can be overridden by a number of other properties. See this link for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/aa369536.aspx.

Comment: **Great note with the log file for debugging.** I had a similar problem and wasted many hours for something simple. After reading so many stuff in the internet and on stack overflow I saw your helping hint. I added log file output to the msiexec command and could see the real problem. For others: Create log files by this: `msiexec /i myInstaller.msi [...] /l myLogfile.txt`

Answer (score 1):

How to use WiX feature conditions is essentially explained here:
https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/getting-started/conditional-installation/

For a feature to be set to the level specified by your condition, the condition has to evaluate to true. You can force it to be true by setting it to 1:

```
<Feature Id="AddinsFeature" Title="InstallAddin" Level="1" Absent="allow">

  <!-- Force condition to be true, which sets the feature to the Level attribute value -->
  <Condition Level="0">1</Condition>

  <ComponentRef Id = "AddInComp"/>
</Feature>
```

Above we force the feature's install level to 0 because its condition of 1 is true (the number 1 is true in MSI logic - by definition - as in boolean). In the real world the condition would be something much more complicated - of course.

Every setup has an overall [INSTALLLEVEL - and it acts as a high water mark as explained here by Chris Painter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504033/129130). Every feature which evaluates to a feature level  below or at the INSTALLLEVEL gets installed by default.

> **Note**: When you set the **`Feature level to 0`** in your WiX source, the feature is **not show in the setup GUI** and it is **not
> going to be installed by default either** (more details in link below).

Feature manipulation can be very involved. A few links:

- [How to install feature based on the property set in custom action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492473/how-to-install-feature-based-on-the-property-set-in-custom-action/49503485#49503485)
- [Unselected Feature Being Installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50515993/unselected-feature-being-installed/50556535#50556535) (over the top detailed)
- [Failing condition wix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863381/failing-condition-wix/49868953#49868953) (Level=0 hides feature from GUI)
- http://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/04/09/feature-states-in-component-conditions/
- https://www.joyofsetup.com/2008/05/16/make-sure-features-are-always-enabled-so-they-can-be-removed/

Answer (score 0):

You can ship the components present inside the feature by setting the condition 'True' like below. Whenever the property 'SAMPLEFEATURE_UNLOCKED' sets to true, the feature is unlocked.
[image]