# How to install a feature dependant on a condition

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm trying to install a feature if the condition is true.

According to tutorials it should work like this:

```
<Feature Id='ParentFeature' Id='Default'
         Title='Wix Sample App'
         Description='The complete package of Wix Sample App.'
         Display='expand'
         Level='1'
         ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLDIR'>

  <Feature Id='ChildFeature' Title='AppConfig Internal' Level='1'>
    <ComponentRef Id='MyApp.exe' />
  </Feature>

  <!-- This is the conditional feature  -->
  <Feature Id='OptionalChildFeature' Title='AppConfig Internal' Level='0'>
    <ComponentRef Id='MyApp.exe.config' />
    <Condition Level='1'><![CDATA[TRUE]]></Condition>
  </Feature>
</Feature>
```

My example results in NOT getting the optional feature installed, but I expected it to get installed.

The resources I used:

- [wix tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/conditional-installation)
- [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22371066/how-to-set-the-level-of-feature-based-on-condition-in-wix)

**Update:**

I tried to make a prototype with  which didn't work.  finally worked and I could identify the problem in previous steps (a property was not correctly set).

Comment: In words, what is the condition you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're condition of "TRUE"  doesn't make sense.  TRUE would be a public property called TRUE. Presumably, nothing set it to have a value so the condition evaluates to false and hence the feature remains at InstallLevel 0 and isn't installed.