# Change product code and name of Project Setup MSI

Tags: windows-installer

Is there a way to change the **product code and name** of msi (Project Setup) through a parameter something like TARGET DIR?

I need to install multiple version (DEV, QA, Stg and Prd) in same machine. So i run my msi in commandline.

C:\Installer\client.msi /qb /l* log.txt TargetDir="C:\Test\**DEV**" ProductCode={*GUID1*}"
C:\Installer\client.msi /qb /l* log.txt TargetDir="C:\Test\**QA**" ProductCode={*GUID2*}"
C:\Installer\client.msi /qb /l* log.txt TargetDir="C:\Test\**STG**" ProductCode={*GUID3*}"
C:\Installer\client.msi /qb /l* log.txt TargetDir="C:\Test\**PRD**" ProductCode={*GUID4*}"

Current Problem:

Commands above are not working.

Comment: This you have to elaborate please.

Answer (score 0):

***Instance Transform***: I suppose the built-in way for this is the [instance transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370326(v=vs.85).aspx), but I am not particularly fond of this construct. Plenty of more information on this in the bolded link below.

***Virtual Machines / Virtual Packages (App-V)***: The modern way to deal with multiple package uses could be to use test virtuals or virtual packages (App-V)? I find this to be the least complicated option packaging-wise. I would recommend it.

***Preprocessor / Compiler Variables***: If you are using WiX, you can try to use compiler variables to allow different versions of your MSI to be compiled from the same source file. Let me just add some links:

- Very long, but hopefully comprehensible: [**Preprocessor use**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449985/wix-installer-setting-component-condition-property-when-doing-a-msiexec-admin/49501700#49501700) (**see towards bottom - sample**)
- Localization variables, preprocessor variables, include files: **[WiX (Windows Installer Xml), Create universal variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444241/wix-windows-installer-xml-create-universal-variables)** (**various forms of advanced WiX source constructs**)
- [WIX If...else condition using registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49564829/wix-if-else-condition-using-registry/49565845#49565845)

---

Some suggestions based on the above topics and a few more options here. These are Stackoverflow and Serverfault links, let me avoid too much duplication by linking (the essence is above):

- [I want to install an MSI twice](https://serverfault.com/questions/54386/i-want-to-install-an-msi-twice/66999#66999)
- **[Installing Multiple Instances by different msi having same Package Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650897/installing-multiple-instances-by-different-msi-having-same-package-code)** (please read fully)