# Install a component in the folder of another program

Tags: installshield

I want to make a setup file by InstallShield 2018. My setup file has two Feature, named MMServer & MMTools. Now I want to MMTools can be installed only if MMServer is selected or ANOTHER program (beyond this setup) named Daric is installed.
In addition to, if Daric is installed I want to install MMTools in Daric Folder.    How can do this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming

Comment: Installscript MSI projects have built-in mechanisms for this, but the project type is not recommended because it features a number of problems and create non-standard MSI files. Some information on [**controlling feature selection**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50556535/129130). And a little more (with more links): [**Short Answer 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52369743/129130) and [**Short Answer 2**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49503485/129130).